# Open attachement from Lotus Notes with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes

I want to open an attachment from Lotus Notes with VBA.
The Problem is that I don't get the path out of Lotus Notes.

[image: Error in Code]

[image: Lotus Notes File]

I would be very thankful if you can give me a code, with how I can open this path without hardcoding it.

Here is the complete Code which does not work...

```
Function OpenURL(URL As String, WindowState As W32_Window_State) As Boolean

'Opens passed URL with default application, or Error Code (<32) upon error

Dim lngHWnd As Long
Dim lngReturn As Long

lngReturn = ShellExecute(lngHWnd, "open", URL, vbNullString, _
vbNullString, WindowState)

OpenURL = (lngReturn > 32)
```

End Function
Sub OpenLotusNotes()

```
Dim objNotesSession As Object
Dim objNotesFile As Object
Dim objNotesDocument As Object

Dim objNotesField As Object
Dim objNotesUIWorkSpace As Object
Dim objNotesView As Object



Set objNotesSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set objNotesFile = objNotesSession.GETDATABASE("ATLAS40", "ACITF\PRODUCTION\USN\ePayable.nsf")
'("Server", "Datenbank")
Set objNotesUIWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkSpace")

Set i = Sheet1.Range("B20")

Dim DocNum As Variant
Dim DocName As Variant
Set objNotesView = objNotesFile.GetView("1.CheckView")
Set objNotesDocument = objNotesView.GetFirstDocument

Dim body As Variant


Dim ms As String
ms = ""

If Not objNotesDocument Is Nothing Then
    'initial set
    DocNum = objNotesDocument.InvoiceNumber
    DocName = objNotesDocument.InvoiceDocumentNumber
    Dim DocFound As Boolean

    DocFound = False

    While Not DocFound = True
        DocNum = objNotesDocument.InvoiceNumber
        DocName = objNotesDocument.InvoiceDocumentNumber



        If DocNum(0) = i Then
            ms = "You are about to open the attachement located in " & DocNum(0) & " " & DocName(0) & " in The Way we do things database from Database Server " & objNotesFile.server & " with Database File name " & objNotesFile.Filename & "."

            MsgBox (ms)
            DocFound = True

            Set body = objNotesDocument.getfirstitem("$FILE")

            'subject der mail ermitteln
            For Each obj In body.embeddedobjects

                'MsgBox (Environ("TEMP") & "\" & obj.Name)
                'MsgBox (obj.Name)
                Call obj.ExtractFile(Environ("TEMP") & "\" & obj.Name)
                OpenURL "file://" & Environ("TEMP") & "\" & obj.Name, Show_Maximized

            Next
        End If
        Set objNotesDocument = objNotesView.GetNextDocument(objNotesDocument)
    Wend
End If
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the actual relevant code. A *screenshot of your code* won't do.

Comment: Re your revised code: you cannot use $File. If you want to use body.EmbeddedObjects, then you need to find the name of the rich text field in which the attachment was embedded. $File is a special object, not a rich text field. Using getFirstItem("body") might be right, but you have look at the form, or look at the field list in the document properties dialog and find the real name used in your application. And even that might not work because sometimes attachments are not saved in a rich text field, in which case the answer I gave in my code still applies: use objNotesDocument.EmbeddedObjects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't open the file by accessing the $File item, so even if you had the correct syntax (using GetFirstItem("$File)) it would still not work.

You need to use `objNotesDocument.EmbeddedObjects()` This will return an array of [NotesEmbeddedObject](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESEMBEDDEDOBJECT_CLASS.html) objects. If there's only one file attachment in the document, there will be only one element in the array. You can use the ExtractFile method of the NotesEmbeddedObject class to save a copy of the file to the filesystem, and you can open it from there.